# WinAPI. Как создать дочернее окно поверх всех окон приложения

Tags: c++, winapi

В приложении есть дочернее окно, которое создается так:

```
windraw.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windraw.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windraw.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    windraw.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windraw.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windraw.hInstance = hInstance;
    windraw.hIcon = NULL;
    windraw.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    windraw.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    windraw.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windraw.lpszClassName = global::drawwz;
    windraw.hIconSm = NULL;
    RegisterClassExW(&windraw);





hwndD = CreateWindowEx(0, global::drawwz, L"General Form", WS_OVERLAPPED, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGTH, 620, 700, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, global::hInst, NULL);
```

Оно должно быть всегда на виду, но постоянно исчезает если кликнуть на любое другое окно приложения, как сделать его всегда сверху?

Comment: что то вроде [`WS_EX_TOPMOST`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно установить флаг [WS_EX_TOPMOST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles) в расширенных стилях окна. Укажите этот флаг в первом аргументе функции [CreateWindowEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw). Либо вызывайте функцию [SetWindowPos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) с аргументом `HWND_TOPMOST` в `hWndInsertAfter`.